# How to launch the G.Projector NASA app on macOS with openJDK?

Tags: macos, java

I'm trying to launch [G.Projector](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/) on macOS M2 but it complains about lack of Java 11. However, I have openJDK and Java installed.

I dowloaded the “requires Mx "Apple silicon" Mac with ARM64 Java” version of the download as [listed here](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/download/).

What can I do to launch the app?

```
> /usr/libexec/java_home -v11
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/20.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

> echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Java JDK 21 [from the official Oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk21-mac) and installed it using the available dmg file. Unfortunately now I have 2 Java installations and JAVA_HOME points to

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home
```